Conditionally use classes for custom tailwind screen sizes
I have a small question. I have custom tailwind screen sizes in my tailwind config and I want to conditionally use classes based on the screen sizes. Is that possible with tailwind? class = "logo tablet: logo-text desktop:logo-text"
Seems like it doesn't work and logo-text doesn't overwrite logo for bigger screens

it is possible. Are you sure you configured custom screen size correct? Share your config and logo, logo-text classes

export default {
theme: {
screens: {
mobile: "430px",
tablet: "750px",
desktop: "1510px",
desktopLarge: "2000px",
}
}
and classes:
.logo1 {
width: 40px;
height: 70%;
background-image: url("../../assets/public/icons/logo_white.png");
}
.logo2 {
width: 220px;
height: 100%;
background-image: url("../../assets/public/icons/logo_white_horizontal.svg");
}
in the HTML div I do 

Custom classes are not applied with breakpoints by default, so you can define styles like this:
@layer utilities {
  .logo1 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 70%;
    background-image: url("../../assets/public/icons/logo_white.png");
  }

  .logo2 {
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../../assets/public/icons/logo_white_horizontal.svg");
  }
}

Now tailwind will apply custom classnames when breakpoint matches.
Also you can specify logo2 class only for tablet breakpoint and it will be applied to desktop and desktopLarge breakpoints because it starts work from min-width. <div class="logo1 tablet:logo2"></div>

yes, this also works and looks much cleaner as you probably don't want to pollute your tailwind.css file. Thanks a lot!

I got it working finally. For anyone wondering it is only possible if you move the classes to tailwind.css in layer directive.


@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components{
    .class1 {
    width: 220px;
    background-image: url(img1)

    }
    .class2 {
    width: 40px;
    background-image: url(img2)
    }
}
<div class ="mobile:class1 tablet:class2"></div>



